# How to launch chrome/chromium browser from win PE?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, chromium, nwjs, winpe

I'm Looking for a method to launch chrome app from Microsoft Win PE.
Is it chrome supported that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no installer for WinPE you need a portable version of a browser.  I've tried the portable version of Chrome but couldn't get it to run in WinPE.  The only browser I've ever seen work in WinPE is an old portable version of FireFox.

If you want to try to get it to work here's the link
https://portableapps.com

In theory it should work but I can't tell what dependencies it needs as there's no error message.  The portable apps are x86 so you have use WinPE_x86.